# Unexpected C++ glitch - incrementation behavior

Tags: c++

When i run this code the var "tarkiz" remains 1. 
Could anyone please explains to me why this happens? isn't it supposed to perform the assignment first (tarkiz = tarkiz) and then increment the value to be 2 instead of 1?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int tarkiz = 1;
    tarkiz = tarkiz++;
    cout<<tarkiz<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Undefined behavior**!

Answer (score 2):

`tarkiz = tarkiz++;` is undefined behavior. To fix it write `tarkiz++;` instead.

See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) for details.